# What does the percentage sign next to some of the intellisense members in Eclipse mean?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I type in `e.` where `e` is an `ActionEvent`, Eclipse's intellisense shows me suggestions. But along with some of them is a percentage at the end of the suggestion.

What is that for?

[image]